# Are we allowed to use the documentation stylesheets?

Tags: design

In interest of keeping with elementary's beautiful documentation, I ported the stylesheets over to SASS and made a Pandoc template. The result looks something like this:

[image: An example adaptation.]

However the [upstream stylesheet](https://github.com/elementary/mvp/blob/master/styles/support.css) says the file is copyright elementary LLC, while [the site's official LICENSE.md](https://github.com/elementary/mvp/blob/master/LICENSE.md) states everything is available under MIT. Since there is no "All rights reserved" marker, and the MIT license is still *technically* a copyright, it seems legal to release/use this.

Would it be considered in the *spirit* of elementary OS to release documentation templates suitable for other developers' workflows in their own eOS applications, or are developers intended to use their own styles (and only sourcing GUI designs from the provided HIG and font styles/color palettes.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Legal

Yes, you can re-use the styles found here. MIT grants you usage rights for pretty much everything. What you cannot do is use the "elementary" name or logomark in such a way as to suggest endorsement.

#### Ethical

Whether or not it is in the "spirit" of elementary to share this work depends on what you are doing with it. Providing a template for use by other developers with better documentation is a noble enough cause, but the true elementary spirit would be making sure that it works consistently and works well.